# JavaFX Android port Listen for volume button presses

Tags: android, javafx

I'm trying to develop an Android app with JavaFX.
Is there a way to listen for volume button presses on my phone so I can launch some code whenever I press volume buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen for various key codes, e.g.

- `KeyCode.ESCAPE` == Back-Button
- `KeyCode.VOLUME_UP` / `KeyCode.VOLUME_DOWN`
- `KeyCode.HOME` - I'm not sure, haven't tested it
- `KeyCode.CONTEXT_MENU` - I'm not sure, haven't tested it

In you Application-Extending Main class you could do something like this:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    // init scene and UI
    scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, this::handleGlobalKeyEvents);
    // do whatever you want
}

private void handleGlobalKeyEvents(KeyEvent event) {
    // use a more specific key event type like
    // --> KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED == event.getEventType()
    // --> KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED == event.getEventType()
    // without it, we would react on both events, thus doing one operation too much
    if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ESCAPE) && KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED == event.getEventType()) {
        if (backHandler != null)
            backHandler.back();
        event.consume();
    }
}
```

Regards,
Daniel